# How can I modify a group of p:selectBooleanCheckboxes with the same class using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have a PrimeFaces `p:selectBooleanCheckbox`:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox styleClass="myCLass" onchange="callsMethod();" value="true" />
```

I want something like this: 
`$('.myCLass').prop( 'checked', true )` for setting the value of the `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `PrimeFaces.getWidgetById` method to get the Primefaces widget for each checkbox having your styleClass assigned:

Toggle all checkboxes having `styleClass="myCLass"`:

```
$('.myCLass').each(function(){PrimeFaces.getWidgetById(this.id).toggle()});
```

Check all checkboxes having `styleClass="myCLass"`:

```
$('.myCLass').each(function(){PrimeFaces.getWidgetById(this.id).check()});
```

Uncheck all checkboxes having `styleClass="myCLass"`:

```
$('.myCLass').each(function(){PrimeFaces.getWidgetById(this.id).uncheck()});
```

Comment: I tested those statements in JavaScript Console, did some copy/past and editing here but I'm very unsure on how those `}` could disappear. Thanks for edit @jasperdevries

Answer (score 3):

It's way easier than that using the widgetVar.

1. Add a widgetVar to your component like...

```xml
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox widgetVar="wgtMyCheckBox" onchange="callsMethod();"  />
```

2. In your Javascript code use the WidgetVar to get or set the value.

```
    PF('wgtMyCheckBox').isChecked(); -- returns current state
    PF('wgtMyCheckBox').check(); -- checks the box
    PF('wgtMyCheckBox').uncheck(); -- unchecks the box
    PF('wgtMyCheckBox').toggle(); -- toggles the current state to the opposite state
```

If you want to check all checkboxes on the screen you can loop over the widgets.

```
for (var widgetVar in PrimeFaces.widgets) {
   var widget = PrimeFaces.widgets[widgetVar];
   if (widget && widget instanceof PrimeFaces.widget.SelectBooleanCheckbox) { 
       widget.check();
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but to set a group? that's why I wanted to use a class

Comment: I just updated my answer to find all widgets of type SelectBooleanCheckbox and check them.  You can obviously modify it to check the style class too if you wanted. but not sure what your use case is